# Count new replies with COUNT function

Tags: php, sql, count

Hello I am trying to get number of unread replies from administrator. Those are support tickets. There are three tables like below.

```
table: supportticket

id | date | username | email | status | subject | message | adminreply | 
admindate | read


table: ticketreplies

id | tid | userid | name | email | date_added | message | admins


table: tickets 

id | userid | trackid | name | email | date_added | title | message | 
status | urgency | lastreply


table: ticket_read 

id | idt | lu
```

I tried this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM first table WHERE to_user_id
=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND `read` = 0";
```

But without success. Hope for more ideas. I am new at this.

```
*when ticket is created by user this table gets update:


tickets

id   |    userid   |   trackid   |    name   |    email     |    date_added     
|    title    |    message   |    status    |    urgency    |    lastreply
456        2           123-456       user     user@user.com    3/23/2017 
15:52      test           test           open            medium        
3/24/2017 15:52



* when admin replies

ticketreplies:

id   |   tid   |    userid   |   name    |   email   |       date_added         
|      message       |   admins    0         456         0                                   
3/23/2017  15:52          replied to test         1

ticket_read

id   |   idt   |  lu
0        456       1
```

p.s. when admin replies tickets table gets status Answered   and lastreply get new date time

check image: prntscr.com/eo0pj2

Comment: how are you storing message and reply in different tables ?

Comment: Please provide table names.

Comment: Please specify things in a clear way.  For instance, what do you mean with "But without success"?  (Post the actual error or the result obtained)...

Comment: i add more details please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is not `to_user_id` but `id` in `first_table` so change like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `first_table` WHERE `id`
='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND `read` = 0";
```

Assuming you have not provided exact table name that why it is `first table` not as `first_name`

Comment: i add more details please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM first table 
  WHERE first_table.id =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND `read` = 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since not much information is given in the question (no logical connection between tables is provided in the question), then in case `id` is just a reference number of the ticket you could try this.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supportticket 
INNER JOIN tickets 
ON supportticket.id=tickets.id
WHERE tickets.userid =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND supportticket.read = 0";
```

**OR this**

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supportticket 
INNER JOIN ticketreplies 
ON supportticket.id=ticketreplies.id
WHERE ticketreplies.userid =".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND supportticket.read = 0";
```

Comment: Tried no result, i have described tables better now please take a look. thanks in advance

Comment: @Andrew11 I have edited my answer, there are fields that are common on your tables but you don't explain for example how they are *logically connected* to each other, meaning for example what is `ticket_read`->`lu` field.? How does it get updated? Does it get updated at all?

Comment: please check i have updated with a little better explain. Check image also. Thats how my table gets updated when ticket is created, and get new reply.

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: can i do something like this:
`<?php $res = $db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM tickets where status='Open'"); $cols1 = $res->fetch_row(); echo $cols1[0]; ?>`

Comment: @Andrew11 you could... what is the difference between table `tickets` and `supporttickets`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question and table structure, You should use `INNER JOIN` to this. And make some changes to your tables.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as admin_replied FROM first_table
INNER JOIN second_table ON first_table.trackid = second_table.trackid
WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND `read` = 0";
```

The first_table should contain **trackid** as your second_table does. This ticket id will be your key to get all the unread reply of admin in a particular user.

But this will be change according on how you store the message and replies to your tables.

Comment: i add more details please take a look.

Comment: @Andrew11 what is `lu` in table `ticket_read` and how do you store data here?